Interaction between microtype and rules
I've had a code for years to make the main title for handouts. Here's a MWE:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{microtype}

\newcommand{\myline}{\rule[0ex]{\textwidth}{.5ex}\\}

\begin{document}

\noindent\myline
[-3ex]
\begin{center}
    \LARGE{\textbf{Foo bar baz}}
\end{center}
\myline

\end{document}

With versions of microtype until at least v3.0f (the latest version in Overleaf), or without microtype loaded at all, this is the output:

With the current version v3.1b, I get this:

Perhaps there are very good reasons for microtype to interact differently with my code for a rule now, or maybe it's a bug - I have no idea. At any rate, what can I do to get the "old" output back?

you shouldn't use \\  at the end of paragraphs. Apart from this, use \leavevmode\Large or \usepackage[nopatch=item]{microtype}.

note \LARGE{\textbf{Foo bar baz}} could better be written as \LARGE\textbf{Foo bar baz}

latex does warn about the mis-placed \\ 

@UlrikeFischer What should I use? \newline? \par? @DavidCarlisle I get no warning about misplaced \\ .

you do get two warnings Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines .... That is from the misplaced \\.
